# App modeller, Identify button not showing up in blueprism spying

Tags: calc, blueprism

I am creating calculator VBO in blueprism object studio.
In application modeller I gave calc.exe path and able to launch calculator, but I am not getting identify option to spy on any element..
In Element, After clicking Launch buttion, identify is appearing for a split of sec and Launch button is coming back instead of Identify

PS- As mentioned in videos and links, I have launched calc via application modeller not directly via windows..
I am using windows 10, BluePrism V.5.0.11.0 version[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4I6w.png)[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 calculator is complicated case, please consider using different application in your training. For example paint is much simpler to get started.

If you really need to get that going, then you may need to launch application first, using one object, and afterwards use second object to attach and interact with it.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response Andrej, you are correct..I'm trying a wedsite to spy now, it's working fine..
I'm dropping from calc spying for now..I will try the method u have mentioned sometime later

Comment: Great, then please mark as answered for that sweet stackoverflow points

Answer (score 1):

can be two reasons
1. Either your application is not launched properly.
2. Sometimes we face problems with some versions of applications.

The best way to fix your problem is

- Edit your settings remove the application path from the navigate stage.
- Launch the application separately
- Open Navigate stage > Action > Attach
- Provide the window title within quotes (example: "Calculator")
- Click OK then run the object
- Now if you go to application modeller
- You will be able to see the identify button under the element.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this attach navigation is creating problem while running complete process flow. it seems it is not releasing application and giving following error "Internal : Failed To perform Step 1 In Navigate Stage 'Attach' on page 'Launch' - Already connected to an application".
and when you remove this attach navigator while running incomplete flow in process studio then it is giving this error:"Internal : Failed To perform Step 1 In Navigate Stage 'Click' on page 'Click Button1' - Not Connected"
Can anybody help here regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by unchecking "Disable invasive techniques (hooking)".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 10 calculator runs with process name `win32calc` which is also located under `c:\windows\system32`.

So when you launch the application please make you identify the applications process name and its location

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by circumventing to windows 7 calculator instead of a windows 10 calculator on windows 10.

Link to download win 7 calculator for win 10-

https://winaero.com/download.php?view.1795

This will be installed in the same place as your default calculator.
Inside-

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

The name of the app in my case was "calc1.exe" to avoid collisions with the default calculator.

I used this as my base reference app for spying and it worked.

Also note, the hover to highlight button seems to be a bit buggy, try a bit hit and trail to get you required button to be highlighted and mark using "Ctrl+LeftClick"