# Attributes of Elements-Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I want to spy an element on Window Calculator using Blue Prism. I launch it using Aplication Modeller, I click Identify but when I keep ctrl pressed and I press left click on a button (element) from calculator nothing happens. My attribute window from Aplication Modeller is still empty. 
I use Windows 10. 
Do you have any solutions? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail? Does the red rectangle for Win32 mode highlight each of the interface elements when you roll over them? What does your Launch stage look like? Have you properly targeted the correct executable or Window Title in your Attach logic?

Comment: The red rectangle for Win 32 is there but it doesn't highlight each of the interface elements when I roll over them. For paint it works fine, it highlights elements and the attributes appear, only for calculator doesn't work.

Comment: I tried installing other calculators. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App modeller, Identify button not showing up in blueprism spying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472511/app-modeller-identify-button-not-showing-up-in-blueprism-spying)

Comment: Please refer to this link I provide my feed back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156602/3072224

Comment: Have you tried using UIA spy mode? It worked for me for Calculator exercise on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the problem by installing the old calculator from Windows 7 on my windows 10 PC.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use AA mode in Blue Prism spying and everything will work fine